# How to hide axes overlay on selected objects

Tags: 3d-view

How can I hide this axis overlay on selected objects?
It's similar to Viewport Display -> Axes but colored.

[image]

Comment: Use Ctrl + . (dot) It corresponds to the option to move origins only

Comment: Finally!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

Which corresponds to the option "Affect only: Origins".

[image]

Comment: ..  I learn a new shortcut every day ...:)

Comment: @RobinBetts, why would we be here if it wasn't for that?

Comment: Thank you! It worked!